# Keys as attributes for ajax calls

Tags: web-development

I have been told its kind of a bad idea to use a key as an attribute of an xml tag. I find the very handy for ajax as i can just stick the key i need in what ever element is being clicked,changed, or whatever. I can see how this is a security risk but have only used the tactic in internal apps.

On external application/sites what would be a better way to handle this. I would assume just embedding another unique field that isn't numeric.

Basic example...
I have a button than when pressed would update the price of an item in the database.

Then using JS on button press i would take the id and pass it back to the controller to update the item.

Comment: You mean placing a security key for access to your remote calls in your HTML?

Comment: No, just the key to some record in the database. I updated the question with a very basic example.

Comment: Just noticed the part about xml tag.  I assume you mean html tag.  Like button ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a problem with that per se.

The controller should validate the request anyway, if a user doesn't have access to something it should be stopped there.

For example,

```
page.php?action=updateAddress&id=7
```

Obviously you want to make sure the request is coming from someone who is allowed to modify ID 7 once you receive it, also a user who can edit the record ID 7 might not have access to edit the record ID 8.

You almost certainly don't want to start litering standard HTML with a bunch of keys like

```
<form ...>
  <input type="text" id="addressL1" name="addressL1" value="123 xyz blvd" addressValue="123 xyz blvd" addressID="6">
</form>
```

If you need them in a form, pass them as hidden fields with their own IDs.

"Be conservative in what you send; be liberal in what you accept."
https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Robustness_principle